# Is there a way to convert graph to data?

Tags: graph, youtube, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

Is there a way to transform a graph (image) into a data table? The graph is not linear, but I know the scale and I can check whatever point (x,y) I want.

Context: I'm trying to store the data of a livestream performance. Youtube doesn't let me export audience data, but there's the interactive graph that shows the coordinates when I put my mouse over.

Example: (I found this on google images) https://coreservices.blog.gustavus.edu/files/2014/12/youtubestats.png

Thanks,
Alessandra

Answer (score 0):

The data is obtainable via YouTube Analytics:

> **Live Stream Metrics**
>
> [...]
>
> YouTube Analytics are also available.
>
> Data is available 48-72 hours after the live stream ends. Data is *downloadable as CSV*.

Source: [Live Stream Metrics](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853833?hl=en)

Comment: I've decided to use another method. But yt analytics live audience data is not downloadable, what you can export as csv is a basic report by country  (total views, peak ccu, time watched and average view duration).